# how do I convert \n and \t to "\n" and "\t" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

My question is simple, I want this string:

```js
//input string
<div class=“element”>
    <span>text</span>
</div>
```

to look like this:

```js
//output string
<div class="element">\n\t<span>text</span>\n</div>
```

First I thought that I can do it with the .replace() function but I don't know how to target the \n and \t in a way that I can replace those.

I use a textbox as in and output.
I need it in one line because I want to writ it to a JSON object and it does not support multiline strings.

Comment: _"because I want to writ it to a JSON object and it does not support multiline strings"_ - Don't write your own JSON... -> `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. Why would you want to preserve HTML indentation? The indentation is only to make it human readable: to the browser it doesn't mean anything. I'd say you should just store it as is.